# Transition according to caption width

Tags: html, image, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm building an image overlay from right to left transition. The transition is working fine but the caption is 45% width of the image and I want the transition to stop at the end of caption width not continue till the end of image width.
This is my code

```css
.screenshot {
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.screenshot > * {
  display: block;
}

.screenshot h3 {
 margin: 8px;
 padding: 0;
 text-indent: 0;
 text-align: right;
 font: 21px/25px "TwCenMT";
 text-transform: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 letter-spacing: normal;
}

.screenshot-caption {
 position: absolute;
 width: 45%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgb(93, 84, 77);
 background: rgba(93, 84, 77, .7);
 color: #ed4e6e;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.screenshot-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.screenshot-caption a {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom:0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2c3e50;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.screenshot-caption > * {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.screenshot-caption_right {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.screenshot:hover .screenshot-caption {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.screenshot:hover .screenshot-caption > * {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="screenshot">
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/200">
  <div class="screenshot-caption screenshot-caption_right">
    <h1>Right to Left</h1>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhp2nL7k/

The transition should be 45% of the image according to caption width

Comment: in `.screenshot-caption` change the  `width: auto;` and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want the transition to stop the end of caption, the absolute position of the caption at that time would be **left = 100-(width of caption div)% = 55%** in this case.

```css
.screenshot {
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.screenshot > * {
  display: block;
}

.screenshot h3 {
 margin: 8px;
 padding: 0;
 text-indent: 0;
 text-align: right;
 font: 21px/25px "TwCenMT";
 text-transform: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 letter-spacing: normal;
}

.screenshot-caption {
 position: absolute;
 width: 45%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgb(93, 84, 77);
 background: rgba(93, 84, 77, .7);
 color: #ed4e6e;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.screenshot-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.screenshot-caption a {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom:0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2c3e50;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.screenshot-caption > * {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.screenshot-caption_right {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.screenshot:hover .screenshot-caption {
  top: 0;
  left: 55%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.screenshot:hover .screenshot-caption > * {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="screenshot">
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/200">
  <div class="screenshot-caption screenshot-caption_right">
    <h1>Right to Left</h1>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```